# Is there any hadith about reciting dua which involves the Dajjal?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, dajjal

Today at prayer I heard the person next to me recite some sort of dua about the Dajjal and the grave in the last tashahud before tasleem. Is there any hadith of the prophet reciting a dua like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is this:

> عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، وَعَنْ يَحْيَى بْنِ أَبِي كَثِيرٍ، عَنْ أَبِي
>   سَلَمَةَ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله
>   عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ إِذَا تَشَهَّدَ أَحَدُكُمْ فَلْيَسْتَعِذْ بِاللَّهِ
>   مِنْ أَرْبَعٍ يَقُولُ اللَّهُمَّ إِنِّي أَعُوذُ بِكَ مِنْ عَذَابِ
>   جَهَنَّمَ وَمِنْ عَذَابِ الْقَبْرِ وَمِنْ فِتْنَةِ الْمَحْيَا
>   وَالْمَمَاتِ وَمِنْ شَرِّ فِتْنَةِ الْمَسِيحِ الدَّجَّالِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>
> Abu Huraira reported: The Messenger of Allah (way peace be upon him)
>   said: When any one of you utters tashahhud (in prayer) he must seek
>   refuge with Allah from four (trials) and should thus say:" **O Allah! I
>   seek refuge with Thee from the torment of the Hell, from the torment
>   of the grave, from the trial of life and death and from the evil of
>   the trial of Masih al-Dajjal" (Antichrist).**

And from this hadeeth you can see the importance of this Dua:

> عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ، أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم كَانَ
>   يُعَلِّمُهُمْ هَذَا الدُّعَاءَ كَمَا يُعَلِّمُهُمُ السُّورَةَ مِنَ
>   الْقُرْآنِ يَقُولُ ‏ "‏ قُولُوا اللَّهُمَّ إِنَّا نَعُوذُ بِكَ مِنْ
>   عَذَابِ جَهَنَّمَ وَأَعُوذُ بِكَ مِنْ عَذَابِ الْقَبْرِ وَأَعُوذُ بِكَ
>   مِنْ فِتْنَةِ الْمَسِيحِ الدَّجَّالِ وَأَعُوذُ بِكَ مِنْ فِتْنَةِ
>   الْمَحْيَا وَالْمَمَاتِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قَالَ مُسْلِمُ بْنُ الْحَجَّاجِ
>   بَلَغَنِي أَنَّ طَاوُسًا قَالَ لاِبْنِهِ أَدَعَوْتَ بِهَا فِي
>   صَلاَتِكَ فَقَالَ لاَ ‏.‏ قَالَ أَعِدْ صَلاَتَكَ لأَنَّ طَاوُسًا
>   رَوَاهُ عَنْ ثَلاَثَةٍ أَوْ أَرْبَعَةٍ أَوْ كَمَا قَالَ ‏.‏
>
> Ibn 'Abbas reported that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) used to teach them
>   this supplication (in the same spirit) with which he used to teach
>   them a surah of the Qur'an. He would thus instruct us: "Say, O Allah,
>   we seek refuge with Thee from the torment of Hell. And I seek refuge
>   with Thee from the torment of the grave, and I seek refuge with Thee
>   from the trial of al-Masih ad-Dajjal, and I seek refuge with Thee from
>   the trial of life and death." Muslim b. Hajjaj said: It has reached me
>   that Tawus said to his son: Did you make this supplication in prayer?
>   He said: No. (Upon this) he (Tawus) said: Repeat the prayer. Tawus has
>   narrated this hadith through three or four (transmitters) with words
>   to the same effect.

Comment: Yes this is the one jazak allahu khayr!

Comment: Try to memorize it. It is an important dua.

Comment: inshallah i will

Comment: Please add the references

Comment: @Zaid References?

Comment: Which collection of Ahadeeth are these narrations found?

Comment: @Zaid First one is from Sahih Muslim 588 https://sunnah.com/muslim/5/162 and the second one from Sahih Muslim 590 https://sunnah.com/muslim/5/170